# Re-render the data in one way binding ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using one way binding in `ng-repeat`. still i want to refresh the `ng-repeat` when the array value is changed.

Please suggest with your ideas:

**Example :**

```
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>
    TO DO List
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/readable/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.1" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp", []).config(function($compileProvider, $httpProvider) {
      $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
    });

    todoApp.controller("ToDoCtrl", function($scope) {

      $scope.data = [12, 23, 45, 67, 89];
      $scope.add = function(dtata) {
        $scope.data.push(dtata);
      }
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">

  <!-- ...elements omitted for brevity... -->

  <div class="panel">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="numberData" />
      <button type="submit" ng-click="add(numberData)">
        add
      </button>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Numbers
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="de in ::data">
          <th>
            {{::de}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The code can be found here at **[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YU3dSLHD7AachnzpeGIR?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

Using the "::" syntax is for *one-time* binding, and should not be confused with *one-way* binding.  `ng-repeat` is, by its nature, one way.  That is to say, adding dom elements will not magically add data items to the model.  The very purpose of one-time binding is to improve performance of angular's digest cycle by declaring explicitly that the data used for rendering will not change (or if it does, we won't care).

Having said that, you could drop the `::` from the `{{::de}}` to eliminate the overhead of checking each item for changes.  If `data` grew to be very large, this would stave off the performance degradation.